# How GTS slots get allocated in Mac 802.15.4 in Castalia Simulator?

Tags: zigbee

I am trying to understand the implementation of 802.15.4 mac protocol ( Mac802154.cc etc. files) in Castalia Simulator for past few weeks.

I am facing some difficulties, which are following:-

1) As per IEEE 802.15.4 standard the coordinator (FFD) node assigns the available GTS slots to nodes (which is requesting GTS slots) on the basis of FCFS approach. I am trying to find out how coordinator node (FFD) is assigning GTS slots as FCFS basis in Mac802154.cc file, but i am unable to understand.

2) How coordinator (FFD) node decides the sequence (order) of nodes, which is requesting GTS slots in  Mac802154.cc file and how can i change the sequence (order) of  GTS requesting nodes ?

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
gulshan soni

Answer (score 0):

It's been many years since I've read the 802.15.4 standard, but from memory, it does not specify how the GTS slots are getting assigned. The FCFS method you mention is simply the simplest (more straightforward) method, and is usually employed when someone needs to implement the 802.15.4 standard, since we need to decide how we will assign GTS slots. But the standard itself does not specify a particular way to assign the slots (or at least it did not in the past, maybe things have changed).

I assume you are using the latest version of Castalia (HEAD of the master branch in GitHub) or at least the version tagged 3.3.

Since Castalia 3.3 we have decided to clearly separate the basic 802.15.4 protocol with how the GTS slots are assigned. This way you can easily implement your own assignment scheme. You'll notice that in the `node/communication/mac/mac802154/` directory you get the basic functionality of the protocol. This part is just the baseline. It is not a complete protocol because it defines no way to assign slots. The most simple way to assign slots is defined in the subdirectory `staticGTS802154`. Here "static" just means that we get a simple FCFS scheme and the assignment does not change from frame to frame.

When you want to use 802.15.4 in your simulations you have to name an actual GTS assignment module. The only one publicly available is staticGTS802154.